# JCA: How to add a RAR to an EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jca

Good day.
Need help with integration of resource adapter RAR in the EAR project.

**Environment**: Windows 10, Wildfly 10, Eclipse neon

The overall **architecture** is the simplest. The adapter consists of a Inbound module only. It receives messages and sends them in the Message Driven Bean.

I created a resource adapter (this is my first experience).
I placed and the adapter itself and the Message Driven Bean in the rar archive (test project). I deploy rar in to the server. **All work correctly** and life is beautiful.

I try connect the RAR to the target system. Nothing to changing in RAR. Just in the Eclipse settings for Connection project i say that it is no longer an independent project but it is part of the Enterprise Project.

I generate the EAR and try RAR in to them. I deploy EAR on the server ... and **error occurs**.

```
00:05:55,548 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" =>"Monro.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Monro.ear\".\"QSSensor.rar\".component.QSSMessageBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.ra.QSSensor]"]} 
00:05:55,630 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] WFLYCTL0183: Service status report WFLYCTL0184:
New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.ra.QSSensor (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Monro.ear"."QSSensor.rar".component.QSSMessageBean.CREATE]
```

The resource adapter is started. I see initialization methods in the log. But Endpoin didn't start because MDB is absent. Code of Message Driven Bean is the primitive.

```
@MessageDriven( messageListenerInterface = IQSSListener.class, 
                activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "29009") })
@ResourceAdapter(value="QSSensor")
public class QSSMessageBean implements IQSSListener{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QSSMessageBean.class.getName());

    public QSSMessageBean() { ; }

    @Override   
    public void onMessage(IQSSMessage theMessage) {
        log.info("I HAVE GOT MESSAGE: "  + theMessage.message() );
    }
}
```

Can someone help to diagnose the problem? Why Message Driven Bean can't start?

Comment: Upvote for "All work correctly and life is beautiful."

Comment: Does your application.xml contain proper module declaration for your resource adapter archive? Is your resource adapter deployed by the time your MDB is being initialized? Also, storing MDBs in a resource adapter archive is a bit nonsensical: those are intended to be used in your business logic, not in a low-level adapter itself.

Comment: _Does your application.xml contain proper module declaration for your resource adapter archive?_ 
Yes, but simple.   Is it correct? <module><connector>QSSensor.rar</connector></module>

Comment: _Is your resource adapter deployed by the time your MDB is being initialized?_ 
Yes. I see initializing string upper in the  log

Comment: _Also, storing MDBs in a resource adapter archive is a bit nonsensical: those are intended to be used in your business logic, not in a low-level adapter itself_
Yes, you are right. But installation and update by "one click" is very important use case.